# Tooltip issue, MatTooltip not working in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip, angular-pipe

I am trying to insert a notifications tooltip in my dashboard page, but the tooltip is not working. I am very new to Angular, so any leads regarding this will be highly appreciated.

**`module.ts`**

```typescript
..
    import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';
..

@NgModule({
..
MatTooltipModule
..})
```

**component.html**

```xml
    <div class="notifications">
        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x" aria-hiden="true" matTooltip="Tooltip!"></i>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To use Angular-Material Tooltip you will need:

1. Import the `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `MatTooltipModule`:

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    // ...
```

2. Add tooltip to your component

**test.component.html**

```xml
<div matTooltip="Tooltip!">Hover me</div>
```

3. P.S If you haven't already installed and imported HammerJs you may need to (Material uses it for some animations and touch gestures):
   `npm i -S hammerjs`
   `npm i -D @types/hammerjs`

And in your app.module.js import hammerjs:

```typescript
import 'hammerjs';
```

To view full working example see: https://stackblitz.com/angular/keqjqmxbrbg

### Update

I found a memory leak in my application, due to extensive use of mat-tooltip (in a loop). This memory leak can be fixed by removing HammerJS.
For more info and other possible solutions (instead of removing HammerJS) see:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4499

Comment: If your app consists of several modules, the import must be in that specific xyz.module.ts.

Comment: I'm unable to get this working with hover.  Long press required to reveal tip.

Comment: I also needed to restart "ng serve" to see the effect of the changes in app.module.ts

Comment: Impossible to make it work after following all available tutorials, thank you google

Comment: import "MatTooltipModule" saved me. thanks

Comment: I added `provideAnimations()` to `app.config.ts` but didn't work

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem. It was fixed when I added the Material theme CSS.

Check the console to see if it has a warning. Try adding the theme CSS to the parent file.

Comment: It might have answered the question, because a missing theme can well be the reason for a non-working matTooltip.

Comment: Not sure if this answered the original users question or not but definitely did the trick for me. If you're just trying to plug tooltip in as the first material component you use and you don't see the tooltip, this could be the problem

Comment: Not the best answer in terms of length, but definitely solve my problem.

Answer (score 11):

If you see an error indicating no theme was found for material, add one of the material themes, like this one, to the first line of your main CSS file;

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Comment: After searching for hours this finally fixed my issue. Why didn't anybody else mention this? Thanks JWP, great hint :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a totally different issue:
I realized after some time, that the tooltip was showing, but behind the `<div>` of the popup-window that I was implementing. So I just could not see it.

For me the solution was to bring it to the front by z-index:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in the import statement
Here's the correct way:

```js
import { MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
```

Comment: That should not make a difference.

Comment: This resolved my issue. `MatTooltipModule` is the module, and `MatTooltip` is the Directive itself.

Answer (score 2):

See it goes like this, if you have separate module for lazy loading or something, then you should re-import MatTooltipModule there.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is rendering elements inside a *ngFor and using matTooltip, I suggest adding **TrackBy** function. That solved my issue.

"*A function optionally passed into the NgForOf directive to customize how NgForOf uniquely identifies items in an iterable.*"
https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was trying to use it inside of a `mat-label`.  Removing it from the label worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the button was disabled, and so apparently the tooltip doesn't display for disabled buttons.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `bootstrapApplication()` to bootstap your app (Angular version >14), add `provideAnimations()` to `providers[]` in app.config.ts

otherwise, add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `imports[]` of the standalone component (or module, in case you don't use standalone components) that uses `matToolTip`