# "renderer.setAttribute()" does not work for matTooltip

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, rendering

I have two components. One for parent and another one for child. I want to set `matTooltip` attribute in parent  component element from child component. I have tried this below:

```
 @ViewChild('contentWrapper') content: ElementRef;// getting parent component element
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.content.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement, 'matTooltip',
      this.content.nativeElement.innerText);

}
```

It's rendered in browser like:

```
<span id="popuptrigger" style="position: absolute;margin-top: -8px" 
mattooltip=" Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales "> Soft drinks, 
coffees, teas, beers,</span>
```

I can see the `mattooltip` attribute in the span element.but I am unable to see the ToolTip .

On the other hand, this is working fine for `title` attribute:

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.content.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement, 'title',
    this.content.nativeElement.innerText);
}
```

Comment: check your matTooltip spelling in template

Comment: No! I am providing correct name on attribute creation. It's converted to lower case during rendering. But the problem is while setting attribute via renderer. it's not reflecting in DOM

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48545417/5049472) helping?

Comment: My bad, does this one help? [Why doesn't Angular matTooltip work when you add it dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239207/why-doesnt-angular-mattooltip-work-when-you-add-it-dynamically)

Comment: @Powkachu No. Because the same reason `The title is a bit slow and I want to add some style to it`

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, wondering if you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I have the same problem. any solution anyone? @RokIvartnik

Comment: In this scenario @KathrineHanson I have used normal `title` with custom css styles as mat tooltip